# Unable to jump to timestamp in Jenkins consoleFull log

Tags: jenkins, logging, console, timestamp, jenkins-plugins

I have timestamp plugin enabled in Jenkins. I am trying to jump to particular timestamp by using elapsed timestamp in URL, as **http://localhost:8080/job/frog/11/consoleFull?elapsed=14:43:11**

Is it possible to jump to timestamp in build log? or is there any error in url ?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot jump to timestamps directly, but **it is possible to skip an arbitrary amount of leading bytes**. E.g., to skip the first million characters, you'd use

```
http://localhost:8080/job/frog/11/logText/progressiveText?start=1000000
```